# Cutting into footing for plumbing?

Tags: plumbing, vent

I am adding a bathroom in my basement on an exterior wall. After cutting out the floor, I can see that the footing extends about 8" in to the space I had planned on putting my vents. Is it OK to remove small parts of the footing to facilitate my vent pipes, or should I change my wall size accordingly so I can still run my vents without disturbing the original footing?

Answer (score 1):

After consulting with a plumber, he advised to leave the footing alone. The first reason was it could potentially lead to foundation cracks in the future, or compromise the wall itself. The second reason is the concrete is so old, it would be a huge undertaking to try and remove any of it.

I opted to move my wall towards the center of the house by 6", which makes the bathroom smaller but negates the need to mess with the footing.